# Issues with web-scraping: Unable to retrieve the right table (Quarterly stock price) from MacroTrends using Tesla stock price

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm want to import data from the Tesla Quarterly Revenues into a pandas data frame. I keep extracting the Annual Revenues table instead (both tables are sides by sides on the webpage). How do I need to modify my code to extract the Quarterly Revenues? Thanks in advance.

````
```html_data  = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html5lib')
tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Revenue'])

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    if (col != []):
        date =col[0].text
        revenue =col[1].text
        tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)

tesla_revenue```
````

Comment: You can use read_html from pandas `import pandas as pd;table = pd.read_html('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue')[1]`   or `soup.select_one('#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table')`

Comment: Make sure to read https://www.macrotrends.net/robots.txt before scraping this site.

Answer (score 2):

To stick with your method you can use the following css selector. Note that I skip the first row which are the headers

---

**Py requests:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html5lib')
tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(
                [{"Date": r.select_one('td:nth-of-type(1)').text, 
                 "Revenue":r.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').text} 
                 for r in soup.select('#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table tr')[1:]]
                , columns = ['Date', 'Revenue'])
print(tesla_revenue)
```

This `#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table tr` select for a parent that has id style-1 that has a child div , via descendant combinator ( ), then moves to the adjacent div with an adjacent sibling combinator (+), then the table element which has class (.) historical_data_table, and finally, via descendant combinator ( ), selects all the rows, tr,  within.

You can test the css within the browser's elements tab by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and enter the css `#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table tr` and hit enter. You can then cycle through the matches.

[image]

You can read about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

---

**Py pandas read_html:**

There is a lot of unnecessary work going on there though.

You could more easily just use pandas read_html and index in for the right table:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue')[1]
print(table)
```

You can find the right index by searching in the elements tab, as described above, but using the css type selector `table` - you will see the second actual table element match is the one you want.

If you examine the page source (right click view source) you will find the table, meaning that content is static and read_html can read it (unless request headers) are required.

---

**Scraping:**

As per the helpful comment by @MichaelLongstreth

Please read the https://www.macrotrends.net/robots.txt for whether scraping is permitted. If it is not permitted, look for a public API serving the same data or another website that does permit scraping.

---